# sql joining two tables on one string match

Tags: c#, sql, linq

This is my linq query -

```
from u in db.CardTables
   join v in db.FunRegistereds
   on new { u.IsApproved, u.FKCardID } equals new {"YES", v.UserID }
```

Where from this query column in first table `CardTables` has one with string match and column `FKCardID` is integer type.

I am getting troubled with this first string match.

How do I match this `u.IsApproved` column with string `"YES"` while matching both the columns in this way ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join on `FKCardID` equals `UserID` and just filter `u.IsApproved`:

```
from u in db.CardTables
join v in db.FunRegistereds
   on u.FKCardID equals v.UserID
where u.IsApproved == "YES"
...
```

Comment: @p.s.w.g thanks, actually I was thinking about your solution :) But decided not to join on query parameter - and added filtering instead :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to give names to the properties in the second anonymous type initializer:

```
from u in db.CardTables
join v in db.FunRegistereds
on new { u.IsApproved, u.FKCardID } equals 
   new { IsApproved = "YES", FKCardID = v.UserID }
```